# How to send chunked response back to browser on completion of thread if running 5 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

Scenario: Submit the form to server; the request will contain IDs of some tasks. 
At the server side (servlet) get the task IDs from the request and then run each task in a separate thread and return the chunked response whenever a thread is completed.

Suppose we have 10 threads running, for whichever thread is complete, the execution needs to return the status to browser.

Could you please suggest the logic?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take the time to integrate a push solution like [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html), [Cometd](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_primer), [Atmosphere](http://async-io.org/tutorial.html) or whatever you like.

Otherwise, the simplest approach that gets you up & running in a minute without learning and integrating anything new is the polling one. You need:

- A servlet to gather input, submit the task to the pool of executors and return the task ID
- A pool of executors
- A servlet that, given a task ID, returns its status - like pending, aborted, succeeded
- A Javascript client that polls the preceding servlet until the work is done (or a timeout expires?)